# Custom React hook in a typescript class

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**TL;DR:**
Can I create a custom hook as a class method (Typescript) ?

**My attempts, function based :**

```
function useMyCustomHookFunction(){
    return useState("this-is-a-test-1");
}
```

```
const [test1, setTest1] = useMyCustomHookFunction()

return (
    <>
         <p>From function: {test1}</p>
    </>
)
```

This works well, my output is :

```
From function: this-is-a-test-1
```

**My attempts, class+method based :**

```
class TestHook {

    private initialValue = "this-is-a-test-2"
    
    public useMyCustomHookMethod(){
        return useState(this.initialValue);
    }

}
```

```
const testInstance = new TestHook()
const [test2, setTest2] = testInstance.useMyCustomHookMethod()

return (
    <>
        <p>From method: {test2}</p>
    </>
)
```

This works also well, my output is :

```
From method: this-is-a-test-2
```

**The problem**

Both solutions works well on runtime, but for the method based, ESLINT is giving me an error :

```
React Hook "useState" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

I cannot find anything on using simple typescript classes for hooks. And I cannot see anything wrong using them. And as far as I know I am not using "class component".

Is that a real problem to use hook methods like this ? Is it simply ESLINT being overzealous ?

Thanks

PS: This is a minimal test code. In my real-life case I plan to use more react and 3rd party hooks (useEffect, useMutation, ...)

Comment: It should work fine. I think eslint just thinks it's a class component, but it's not. You can add a comment to ignore eslint error here

Comment: In my personal opinion, having hooks organized like this does not bring much value, rather it could pose confusion for other people reading your code. Usually hooks are functions that are called directly, not in this way. To your credit, this is an interesting mash of concepts and is totally legal, but for the sake of readability u would avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

For this issue, you can simply add a exclusion comment for ESLint so that you are not bothered with this warning:

For the line: `/* eslint-disable-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks */`
For the whole file: `/* eslint-disable react-hooks/rules-of-hooks */`

---

**Sidenote (extracted my comment)**
In my personal opinion, having hooks organized like this does not bring much value, rather it could pose confusion for other people reading your code. Usually hooks are functions that are called directly, not in this way.

To your credit, this is an interesting mash of concepts and is totally legal. However, I, personally, always go first with readability rather than making a reusable code that for this environment is not commonly seen.

This does look more of a Angular-ish way of writing services.

Comment: Thanks
For us it's a good way to allow us the use of interfaces and like this we can abstract concrete services and keep being integrated with React stuff. 

On the readability, yes it adds a layer of complexity. But all the concerned methods starts with "useXXX" so it should be easy to keep track of what is a hook and what is not.

Comment: Got it. What is usually do is either scope a hook inside the folder of the component that uses it, or extract it into a `common/hooks` folder where it is shared all over the place. All of this is a flavour of the developer :) if you agree that this is a conventions and you keep with it, than you are good to go!